# SpriteKit location of SKSpriteNode on screen

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I've got a really simple problem, but I've not been able to find a solution...how do I get the screen coordinates of a `SKSpriteNode`, given that its `position` property is `CGPoint.zero` but that its a number of children down from the `SKScene` and each parent will have applied some translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'll want to use `convert(_ point: CGPoint, to node: SKNode)` and `convert(_ point: CGPoint, from node: SKNode)`

you'll probably have to use both

example

```
let nestedSpritePos = convert(convert(nestedSpritePos.position, from: nestedSpritePos.parent!), to: self)
```

assuming self is the scene. You may have to play around with those but they definitely are what you are looking for.

Comment: No need to do it twice. `scene.convert(position,from:node)`. Will take you from node to scene.  `node1.convert(position,from:node2)` will take your position from node2 go up to scene, then down to node1

Comment: great to know! Honestly I find the "convert" funcs the single most poorly written func for description in the Apple docs